# React Native – Make View bigger than container View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to implement such two Views:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmlQW.jpg)

I made it this way:

```
<View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: colors.bigStone,
          height: 2,
          width: '100%',
        }}>
        <View style={styles.bluePoint} />
      </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bluePoint: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    backgroundColor: colors.bluePoint,
    borderRadius: 64,
    height: 4,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    marginBottom: 2,
    width: 4,
  },
}
```

But it looks this way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNt11.png)

How can I center it?
Adding margin and padding doesn't help.
As I think, my view can't go upper of the top of its container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.separatorWrap}>
                        <View style={[styles.separator, styles.marginright]}/>
                        <Text style={styles.separatorText}><Avatar.Icon size={36} /></Text>
                        <View style={[styles.separator, styles.marginleft]}/>
                    </View>
      </View>
```

- i used `react-native-paper` icons you can use something else also

  ```
    container: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  separatorWrap: {
        paddingVertical: 10,
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    separator: {
        borderBottomWidth: 15,
        flexGrow: 1,
        borderColor: "#8BDA9F",
    },
    separatorText: {
        color: "#eee",
        fontSize: 13,
        zIndex:1
    },
    marginright:{
      marginRight: -20
    },
    marginleft:{
      marginLeft: -20
    }
  ```

Example working code: https://snack.expo.io/nbAKOYFlr

Output : [image: screenshot]